# pixman 0.34.0 ios, android build

Tags: cairo, pixman

I'm trying to build pixman-0.34.0 (http://cairographics.org/releases/) for iOS and Android.

There list of options for ./configure script:

- --disable-libtool-lock  avoid locking
- --disable-openmp        do not use OpenMP
- --disable-loongson-mmi  disable Loongson MMI fast paths
- --disable-mmx           disable x86 MMX fast paths
- --disable-sse2          disable SSE2 fast paths
- --disable-ssse3         disable SSSE3 fast paths
- --disable-vmx           disable VMX fast paths
- --disable-arm-simd      disable ARM SIMD fast paths
- --disable-arm-neon      disable ARM NEON fast paths
- --disable-arm-iwmmxt    disable ARM IWMMXT fast paths
- --disable-arm-iwmmxt2   build ARM IWMMXT fast paths with -march=iwmmxt
                        instead of -march=iwmmxt2
- --disable-mips-dspr2    disable MIPS DSPr2 fast paths
- --disable-gcc-inline-asm
                        disable GNU-style inline assembler
- --enable-static-testprogs
                        build test programs as static binaries [default=no]
- --enable-timers         enable TIMER_BEGIN and TIMER_END macros [default=no]
- --enable-gtk            enable tests using GTK+ [default=auto]
- --enable-libpng         Build support for libpng (default: auto)

What is not needed for iOS and Android platforms?

Answer (score 1):

I have built Pixman/Cairo for iOS by crafting a makefile from this mapnik one which you can find here: https://github.com/PaulWagener/mapnik-ios-framework/blob/master/Makefile

In my experience with it building it for iOS there remains to be good intrinsics support for ARM NEON instructions and as a result performance was not good for what I was doing which was blitting frames from a Cairo Surface into GLES 2. If there is a better solution for this I would be interested. Here is an [older discussion](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/pixman/2012-February/001714.html) on the topic however I have not been able to get this approach to work.

For Android I have heard there is good support for Cairo/Pixman and even a GLES 2 backend. Check out the makefiles in android-cairo and android-cairogles github projects. If you decide to use hardware gpu extensions (GLES) your project will lose its portability.

To answer your question directly none of those features are needed except including the libpng library most likely.